# Cannot Install R Packages from github

Tags: r, git, curl, github

```
devtools::install_github("google/CausalImpact")
```

Hi, I'm trying to install the CausalImpact package from github.  However, I keep getting the error below.  I have seen some code fixes posted previously for similar issues (something along the lines of PHP fixes; forgive my meager coding experience, but I have no clue what that even means), but none seem to work for me.  What can I do to remedy this?
I appreciate the help, thanks.

```
Downloading GitHub repo google/CausalImpact@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/google/CausalImpact/zipball/master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates
```

Comment: It installed ok for me; I am on a Mac using R 3.2.3 and RStudio. You may want to give some version information that others may find useful (e.g. platform, R version, devtools version, RStudio version if relevant).

Comment: I can suggest downloading the package as a zip file, unzipping and then installing from this local copy. This may not work on Windows, though.